# CountDistinct to return negative values gives #error

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I'm writing a simple expression to count distinct values in my sql query. For a subset of properties, if they equal "lost/sold" I want them to be negative, but I am receiving *#Error*. Any idea why this is?

```
=Countdistinct(IIF(Fields!PortfolioChangeStatusCodeID.Value="Lost/Sold",Fields!LeaseNumber.Value*-1,Fields!LeaseNumber.Value))
```

[image]

Comment: can you please tell us in which case it shows #Error - Sample value please!!

Comment: It is numeric. The equation works fine if i just use `=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!PortfolioChangeStatusID.value = "Lost/Sold", Fields!LeaseNumber.value *-1))` however, with the second condition, it is erroring out my negative values. Currently those values = 6 and 31 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Fields!LeaseNumber.Value is either null or not numeric. Checking for both would solve this.

Clearly, there is no need to check for both if (for instance) the value could never be null.

```
=Countdistinct( IIF(Fields!PortfolioChangeStatusCodeID.Value="Lost/Sold",ISNOTHING(CINT(Fields!LeaseNumber.Value),0)*-1,ISNOTHING(CINT(Fields!LeaseNumber.Value),0)))
```

Comment: I believe there is an issue with your expression as I return a too many arguments error

Comment: Maybe - not bad from memory though. You get the idea!